# Is it possible to hide the stack trace when testing with PHPUnit?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

Is there a way to get rid of the stack trace when I am testing (Laravel 5.3 PHPUnit)?

I keep getting a load of this:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /u10/html/utils/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(77): PDO->prepare('select * from "...', Array)
#1 /u10/html/utils/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(333): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->prepare('select * from "...')
#2 /u10/html/utils/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(763): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\SQLiteConnection), 'select * from "...', Array)
#3 /u10/html/utils/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(726): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from "...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /u10/html/utils/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(351): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from "...', Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /u10/html/utils/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1648):
```

Comment: But why? Since you're in testing, it would be better if you know the stacktrace of something that doesn't work.

Comment: Keeps filling the screen and I only want to see the top message.

Comment: What does your test look like? Can't tell what is going on here, really.

Comment: Top message: stop on first error/warning/whatever (`--stop...`) , for the "top" message, use a pager (e..g `less`) or `head`. Don't re-invent the wheel. The stacktrace is useful anyway, so probably a pager is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to hide the stack trace and only see the first few lines

Answer (score 0):

use

```
php artisan test --filter [name]
```

it will show better error display.